# How to keep my cameras preset rotation when tracking an object

Tags: camera

I have a camera following a bezier circle and tracking a stationary empty object. I have the camera angle and rotation set specifically to begin with but when I choose the object to track to with world space in target and owner the rotation aligns to the world axis. when set to local or custom in either field it keeps my rotation initially but as soon as the camera starts moving it no longer keeps that rotation.  is there a way to keep my specified camera rotation throughout its motion along the path?

In the first pic there is no object constraint, the second is with the target and owner set to world space, as you can see the camera orientation changes but it keeps this orientation throughout the follow path.  the third pic the camera regains its initial orientation by changing to local or custom but now does not keep a fixed orientation throughout its journey along the path.  can I have the initial orientation and have it remain constant throughout its journey?

[image]
[image: without track to]
[image: Camera loses my presetup orientation but keeps constant throughout following path][image: Camera starts with my preset orientation but does no keep it throughout rotation (stays relative to path not track to object)]

Comment: i tried it...it works. please provide blend file. and maybe add a screenshot what happens and how you want it so we do not misunderstand you. Thanks.

Comment: how do i add .blend, host it on a third party site and link?

Comment: Open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: Awesome, I feel like this should be pinned to the top of the ask question screen...

Comment: You are right…..!

Comment: so you want this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Pnc.gif

Comment: I want that but with the camera orientation to be set as it is in my first picture, aligned to the rotation of the empty, not the world orientation.

Comment: i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

you get this by doing this:

1. unparent your cam
2. set origin of your beziercircle to 0,0,0
3. add follow path object constraint to cam
4. add track to object constraint to cam and change to local

copy the rotation values from empty to cam.

result:

[image]

result:

[image]

blend file: [image]

Comment: so, when I add the follow path constraint, the camera doesn't actually move, just the little blue line.  I previously have just used the parent > follow path command.  What else do I need to do to get the follow path constraint to work?

Comment: The only way I can get the camera to follow the path with the follow path constraint is to parent it to the object but then it does not keep its orientation locked to the empty or the world origin, but to the circle, what step am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check my blend file? Is this the result you want?

Comment: not quite, in your .blend file, the target and owner are set to world space not local like in your picture, and the camera is accordingly oriented to the world orientation (level with the xy plane) not to the rotation of the empty.  I would like the camera to follow the path but to be oriented to the empty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the solution.  The "target Z" option in the track to constraint allows you to switch from tracking with the "up" for the camera being the world z axis to the z axis of the tracked object.  bam.